# Laravel 5.8 Contextual Binding with parameters, DI and mock never work

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, mocking

## Contextual Binding

```
$this->app->when(ImportCommand::class)
->needs(Foo::class)
->give(function() {
   return new Foo(env('IMPORT_BAR'));
});
```

## Dependency Injection in constructor of ImportCommand class

This works fine:

```
public function __construct(Foo $foo) {
   // Foo with the argument is now injected
}
```

## For testing class ImportCommand, I need to mock

I want to mock Foo in my Import Test Class, but this does not work.

```
   $this->mock(Foo::class, function ($mock) {
      $mock->shouldReceive([
         'login' => true,
         'get' => true,
         'rename' => true,
      ]);
   });
   $this->artisan('foo:bar');
```

Calling the artisan command, the *real Foo class will be used instead of the mock*. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

After encountering the same problem and trying a few things, I found the containers `extend()` method works best.

```php
$this->app->extend(Foo::class, function () {
    return \Mockery::mock(Foo::class, function($mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive([...]);
    });
});
```

Other things I tried,unsuccessfully

- `Container.afterResolve()`
- `Container.bind()`
- `TestCase.swap()`
- `TestCase.instance()`

Comment: First of all, big thanks for that. It's working perfectly fine. Wanna throw some light on why it works?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to contextual bind it, it's not clear from my point of view how you mock it, but assume you can get the mocked instance with `Mockery` or similar you can bind the instance, with the `addContextualBinding` method. The instance needs to be wrapped in a `closure` and returned.

```
$mockedInstance = something();

$this->app->addContextualBinding(
    ImportCommand::class,
    Foo::class,
    function() use($mockedInstance) {
        return $mockedInstance;
    }
);
```